# CSS3 transition not working initially when triggering via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I'm using jquery to trigger with a div's hover another div's resize:

```
$("#lggroup").hover(function()
{
    $("#register").css("width", "200px");
}, function()
{
    $("#register").css("width", "0px");
});
```

The second div has a transition effect upon it that doesn't affect the change initially but it does after the second hover.

```
transition: width 0.25s;
```

Although not breaking, the sudden width expand has an unpleasing effect.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tu9keje5/1/

You can see that initially after running the fiddle, the main div expands suddenly because of the gray div expanding suddenly. Afterwards the transition kicks in fine. Any workarounds or causes for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give `#register` an initial `width` value:

```
#register {
    transition:width 0.25s;
    width: 0px;
}
```

**[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tu9keje5/2/)**

Comment: Neat, so jquery/javascript should have an initial value for a css (edit: a defined initial value)

Comment: the initial value is `undefined`  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the CSS, you are trying to animate the width, but the initial with doesn't exist and so there's no animation. For the second time you do it, the width does exist and animates. Change your register css for this (I also placed a height equal to the other divs):

```
#register
{
    width:0;
    height:400px;
    transition:width 0.25s;
}
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tfcrdjka/

Comment: `#` is an id, not a css class

Comment: Sorry, my fault writing that